# element must be in the set?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I know this is quite general, but I can't pinpoint when I specifically see this, usually in real analysis proofs. I always see in proofs that first they point out that an element is in the set, so the set is non empty, why do the mathematicians make this step? sorry if I am unclear or not very specific, because I want to know not to a specific case. Also English is not my first language so pardon my English..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some proofs. Empty set is trivially satisfy the statement .For example:A closed subset $A$ of a compact space $X$ is compact.
In the proof we assume $A$ is non empty. If $A$ is empty  then $A$ is closed (empty set is open as well as closed) and empty set is compact(why). So there is nothing interested. So we first assume It is non-empty.